Get duty time and accumulated working hours using SQL query
Need to get duty time and accumulated working hours.
Have two tables employee and working hours.
calculate duty time as work_end_date_time - work_start_date_time and
calculate accumulated hours by adding duty_hour based on input date passed
employee table
empid workid
1       6
2       7
3       8

wroking_hours table
workid work_start_date_time work_end_date_time
6      1-sep-2024 9:00        1-sep-2024 20:00
6      2-sep-2024 22:00       3-sep-2024 6:00
6      4-sep-2024 6:00        4-sep-2024 10:00

Output table should be like (if I pass 4-sep-2024 as base date then)
empid accumulation_date duty_time accumulated_working_hours
1        4-sep-2024        4:00         4:00
1        3-sep-2024        0:00         4:00    
1        2-sep-2024        8:00         12:00
1        1-sep-2024        11:00        21:00       

Here is my basic query and what I have tried,
Select 
    a. empid , 
    b.work_start_date_time , 
    b.work_end_date_time, 
    FLOOR((b.work_end_date_time-b.work_start_date_time)*24) + ((b.work_end_date_time-b.work_start_date_time)*24-FLOOR((b.work_end_date_time-b.work_start_date_time)*24))/100*60 as duty_time
    --SUM(duty_time) over() as accumulated_duty_hours
from 
    employee a, wroking_hours b
where 
    a.empid=1 and 
    a.workid = b.workid and 
    b.work_start_date_time BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2024-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2024-09-5', 'YYYY-MM-DD')


You rather can simply use date'2024-09-01'.

You can use a row-generator to create a calendar and then join your table to it and total the hours:
WITH bounds (start_date, end_date) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2024-09-01', DATE '2024-09-05' FROM DUAL
),
calendar (day) AS (
  SELECT start_date + LEVEL - 1
  FROM   bounds
  CONNECT BY start_date + LEVEL - 1 < end_date
)
SELECT e.empid,
       c.day AS accumulation_date,
       COALESCE((w.work_end_date_time - w.work_start_date_time) * 24, 0)
         AS duty_hours,
       COALESCE(
         SUM(w.work_end_date_time - w.work_start_date_time) OVER (
           PARTITION BY w.workid
           ORDER BY c.day DESC
         ) * 24,
         0
       ) AS accumulated_duty_hours
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN working_hours w
       PARTITION BY (w.workid)
       ON (   c.day <= w.work_start_date_time
          AND w.work_start_date_time < c.day + 1
          )
       INNER JOIN employee e
       ON (w.workid = e.workid)
WHERE  e.empid = 1;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE employee (empid, workid) AS
SELECT 1, 6 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE working_hours (workid, work_start_date_time, work_end_date_time) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-09-01' + INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-09-01' + INTERVAL '20:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-09-02' + INTERVAL '22:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-09-03' + INTERVAL '06:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-09-04' + INTERVAL '06:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-09-04' + INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



EMPID
ACCUMULATION_DATE
DUTY_HOURS
ACCUMULATED_DUTY_HOURS




1
2024-09-04 00:00:00
4
4


1
2024-09-03 00:00:00
0
4


1
2024-09-02 00:00:00
8
12


1
2024-09-01 00:00:00
11
23



fiddle

But I need based on empid.

@Saran In the question you state a.empid = b.workid so they are identical. You can either rename the column or add another join to the employee table. fiddle

My bad. Work id's are same but not the empid which I separately pass. Am trying to alter the query you provided. Not successful yet.

@Saran Updated to join the employee table.
